# Producing video for multiple platforms

Tags: ffmpeg, premiere, adobe-media-encoder, rendering

I want to create videos for multiple platforms. For example youtube and a private school.

Now the thing is that I want certain lower thirds to appear on one rendered video and another set to appear on another video.

For example, I want a subscribe and social media lower thirds to appear on the youtube video and I want the school email and other relevant info to appear on the second video.

Currently what I am doing is to create two sequences in premiere and basically re-edit and change the mogrts.

The problem with this is that it is monotonous and I have to do it for each and every video individually.

Is there a way I can streamline this using ffmpeg or any other software?

Maybe I can render my video first without any lower thirds, then create a transparent video of my lower third animations and have them be inserted automatically at a specific time interval.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that your 'lower thirds' are images, and are not dynamically generated. For example you have `youtube-l3rd-1.png`, `youtube-l3rd-2.png`, and `youtube-l3rd-3.png` for YouTube, and `school-l3rd-1.png`, `school-l3rd-3.png`, and `school-l3rd-3.png` for school.

You then create a way to put those thirds on the video with `-filter_complex` of `ffmpeg`. Since this was not your question, i am assuming that you did so. You can then do:

```
for platform in youtube school
do
  ffmpeg -i input.ogv -i "${platform}-l3rd-1.png" -i "${platform}-l3rd-3.png" -i "${platform}-l3rd-3.png" ..... "${platform}-output.ogv"
done
```